# Zend Framework - join query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, join

I build a function

```
public function getBannedByLogin($commentId)
    {
    $sql = $this->getDbAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('comments' => 'comments'), array())
            ->join(array('users' => 'qengine_users'),
            'comments.bannedBy = users.userId',
            array())
            ->where('commentId = ?', $commentId)
        ;
        $row = $this->fetchRow($sql);
        return $row['login'];

    }
```

And there are problems, that does'nt work! :D
Let's I explain you. Column 'bannedBy' from comments returns id of user, who give a ban. I need to join this with table users to load a login field. Where i have mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the code works in the sense of not throwing an exception. If so, your code is OK, you just specifically tell `Zend_Db` not to select any columns.

```
public function getBannedByLogin($commentId)
{
$sql = $this->getDbAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('comments' => 'comments'))
        ->join(array('users' => 'qengine_users'),
        'comments.bannedBy = users.userId')
        ->where('commentId = ?', $commentId)
    ;
    $row = $this->fetchRow($sql);
    return $row['login'];

}
```

The last argument to `from()` and `join()` functions is an array of columns you wish to select. If you pass in an empty array, no columns are selected. No argument = select everything. You can, of course, specify only the columns you need too.